# Suicide statistics

Tags: medical

I am doing a project and I am having trouble finding statistics about suicide and links to depression, anxiety and alcohol abuse. I'm not sure if this is where to ask, but if you could help me, that would be appreciated.

Comment: http://asdfree.com/national-study-on-drug-use-and-health-nsduh.html surveys the us population on drug use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> National Violent Death Reporting System (NVDRS) provides states and communities with a clearer understanding of violent deaths to guide local decisions about efforts to prevent violence and track progress over time. NVDRS is the only state-based surveillance (reporting) system that pools data on violent deaths from multiple sources into a usable, anonymous database. These sources include state and local medical examiner, coroner, law enforcement, toxicology, and vital statistics records.
>
> NVDRS covers all types of violent deaths—including homicides and suicides—in all settings and for all age groups. NVDRS may include data on mental health problems; recent problems with a job, finances, or relationships; physical health problems; and information about circumstances of death. Such data is far more comprehensive than what is available elsewhere.
>
> Data are available online to the general public through CDC’s [WISQARS (Web-based Injury Statistics Query and Reporting System).](https://www.cdc.gov/violenceprevention/nvdrs/index.html)

For a more global view you may want to look at the World Health Organization [suicide data](http://www.who.int/mental_health/prevention/suicide/suicideprevent/en/).

Also Our World in Data has a page on [suicide](https://ourworldindata.org/suicide).